# advise hql for the below sql

Tags: hibernate, hql

Below is the sql query which will fetch the results which is  a combination of many inner joins..and the corresponding pojos are

```
 Table             JAVA POJO
    rtyuUSER          User
    rtyu_GROUP         rtyu
```

user.java contains the following properties

updatedby
    updatebby
    updateddate

rtyu_GROUP.java contain the following properties

id;

```
code;
```

name;

The query which fetches the record..
    SELECT distinct u.name, u.updated_by, u.updateddate FROM rtyuUSER u, rtyuuser_rtyu ug, rtyurtyu gwhere u.id = ug.user_id and ug.rtyu_id = g.id and u.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' and g.id not in (10,11) order by u.name

and the relationship between tables is defined in the hbm as ,

```
<class name="User" table="rtyu_USER" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="true">
<property name="name" type="string" />
<property name="updated" type="timestamp" column="UPDATEDDATE"  />
        <property name="updatedBy" column="UPDATED_BY" type="string"/>
        <property name="active" type="yes_no" column="FLAG" />
        <set name="groups" table="rtyu_USER_GROUP" lazy="true" inverse="false" sort="natural">
            <key column="USER_ID" />
            <many-to-many column="GROUP_ID" class="Group" />
        </set>


        and the nother class tag is defined as..

        <class name="Group" table="rtyu_GROUP" mutable="false">
        <id name="id" unsaved-value="0" type="long" access="property" />
        <property name="code" type="string" />
        <property name="name" type="string" />
        <set name="permissions" table="rtyu_GROUP_PERMISSION" inverse="true" lazy="false" sort="natural">
            <key column="GROUP_ID" />
            <many-to-many column="PERMISSION_ID" class="Permission" />
        </set>
    </class>



Now could you please advise how to write HQL for this for this..folks please advise for this
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Active users not part of groups 10 and 11?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, it's going to be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM
User u
INNER JOIN u.groups as g
WHERE u.active='Y' AND g.id NOT IN (10,11)
ORDER BY u.name
```

Comment: but as observe in database there are three tables that are linked together but in hql there are two relationships that you seen as you can see in the first class tag there is a set

Comment: you're right. What's the relationship between User and rtyu? Where is it defined in your hbm?

Comment: see the first class tag that it contains set so that is an intermedtiaery table and that waht I am stuck

Comment: rtyu_USER_GROUP relationship is missing and that is shown in hbm

Comment: HQL uses JOIN differently than regular SQL. rtyu_USER_GROUP is not a problem. I need to know where is class associated with rtyurtyu.

Comment: see running your query is throwing exception q, i have debugged and cross checked my ultimate goal is to make hql of this sql..The query which fetches the record.. SELECT distinct u.name, u.updated_by, u.updateddate FROM rtyuUSER u, rtyuuser_rtyu ug, rtyurtyu gwhere u.id = ug.user_id and ug.rtyu_id = g.id and u.ACTIVE_FLAG='Y' and g.id not in (10,11) order by u.name..and I am stuck on this

Comment: among classes there is main class user which has a set groups which is representing the intermediatery table and there is a second class Group.

Comment: If I understood you right, then your xml is not correct. It should be <set name="groups" table="rtyuuser_rtyu"...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have updated the post there are two pojos as you can see one is user.java which contains a set also and there is another pojo named rtyu_GROUP